# plutus-pab still not building

Tags: plutus-playground, plutus-pab

I had plutus-playground up and running with a prior commit, but am trying to get the latest version running. I have cloned everything fresh in a new folder. I have successfully run the following inside the plutus-apps directory.

> ```
> git checkout 41149926c108c71831cfe8d244c83b0ee4bf5c8a
> nix-build -A plutus-playground.client
> nix-build -A plutus-playground.server
> nix-build -A plutus-playground.generate-purescript
> nix-build -A plutus-playground.start-backend
> ```

Now I am at plutus-pab. I am in bash. I have tried the following and received the following errors:

> bash-3.2$ nix-build -A plutus-pab
> error: attribute 'plutus-pab' in selection path 'plutus-pab' not found
> bash-3.2$ GC_DONT_GC=1 nix-build -A plutus-pab
> error: attribute 'plutus-pab' in selection path 'plutus-pab' not found
> bash-3.2$ nix-build ./default.nix -A plutus-apps.haskell.packages.plutus-pab
> Segmentation fault: 11
> bash-3.2$ GC_DONT_GC=1 nix-build ./default.nix -A plutus-apps.haskell.packages.plutus-pab
> this derivation will be built:
>   /nix/store/yz5wyg4yv21xvwq9nmwb3bcb6fcvx30y-plutus-pab-0.1.0.0-coverage-report.drv
> building '/nix/store/yz5wyg4yv21xvwq9nmwb3bcb6fcvx30y-plutus-pab-0.1.0.0-coverage-report.drv'...
> sandbox-exec: pattern serialization length 83683 exceeds maximum (65535)
> error: builder for '/nix/store/yz5wyg4yv21xvwq9nmwb3bcb6fcvx30y-plutus-pab-0.1.0.0-coverage-report.drv' failed with exit code 65;
>        last 1 log lines:
>        > sandbox-exec: pattern serialization length 83683 exceeds maximum (65535)
>        For full logs, run 'nix log /nix/store/yz5wyg4yv21xvwq9nmwb3bcb6fcvx30y-plutus-pab-0.1.0.0-coverage-report.drv'.
> bash-3.2$ GC_DONT_GC=1 nix-build ./default.nix -A plutus-pab
> error: attribute 'plutus-pab' in selection path 'plutus-pab' not found
> bash-3.2$

This is really feeling like broken code. What needs to be fixed to get this to work?

Comment: Which instructions are you following? The `plutus-pab` is a library.

Comment: The "canonical" instructions here, step 11.  https://docs.plutus-community.com/docs/setup/MacOS.html  I've gotten those other variations of the instructions for elsewhere, including Discord. Libraries still need to be built, don't they? My understanding is that all this code is actively being developed and changing. This does not act like a stable commit.

Comment: The issues you are seeing are from the `nix` tool that's being used. Sorry for asking more questions, as I can't reproduce this. What operating system is this, and what does `nix --version` report?

Comment: macOS Catalina 10.15.7 on two separate machines. Nix version 2.51. The problem may have been due to having "sandbox - true" in /etc/nix/nix.conf. That was a suggestion elsewhere but appears to not be currently correct. I now have everything successfully running and am attempting to re-trace my steps on another virgin machine (Mojave) while carefully documenting (for future generations!) what actually works for me, today.

Comment: Yes. `sandbox = true` on macOS with nix is not well supported at all. Especially not with more complicated nix expressions.